# Access Context in non react component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Imagine, a user logs in (for the first time). This would need a few updates

- Store token and some config in storage
- Update Context so that widgets render

One option is to call above methods from within handler. I want to encapusalate all such login in a service method like

**Services/UserService.js**

```
const context = useContext(UserContext) //err
const RegisterSocialLogin = (userData, tokenData)=>{
 //put data in async storage/sql
 //update some UserContext using useContext
}
```

Problem - This service isn't a React component and UseContext throws error. One option is to pass context from the calling component but that would make it complex. Is it possible to access Context in a non react component  without being passed from outside?